# Animations stutter on the first run in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, preload

I've tried looking through at least half a dozen questions on here and I can't seem to figure out how to properly preload the images. The first run always lags for each animation to the point where i lose probably 25% of the frames. It's not the most noticeable thing, but it's definitely apparent. After that, when they've loaded it doesn't stutter anymore. They're relatively short animations, none being longer than 20 PNG's.

My image array is

```
{
    Stickman.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL4.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL5.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL6.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL7.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL8.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL9.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL11.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL11.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL12.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL13.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL14.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL15.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL16.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL17.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL18.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL19.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL20.png"],

                                 nil];
    [Stickman setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    Stickman.animationDuration = 1.52;
    [Stickman startAnimating];
}
```

At first I thought it was simulator lag, but when I tried it out on a real device it still had the same issues.

Comment: Can you solve it by "seeding" the animation engine with a previous animation consisting of blank images?

Comment: Also, does it make any difference if you call `startAnimating` in a very short (e.g. `0.1`) GCD delay?

Answer (score 1):

1st - you need try load images array before startAnimation (application did finish, view did load for example)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    Stickman.animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL1"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL2"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL3"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"DAL4"]];
    [Stickman setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    Stickman.animationDuration = 1.52;
}

- (void)startYourAnimation {
    [Stickman startAnimating];
}
```

2nd - try to use timer and custom animation class.

```
- (void)startAnimation {
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.25f target:self selector:@selector(hideandview) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)stopAnimation {
    if (timer != nil) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)nextFrame {
    frame++;
    if (frame > frameNumber) {
        frame = 0; // For cycle
    }
    Stickman.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DAL%d", frame]];
}
```

3rd - optimize your image resources (dimension, extension) - .jpeg is less demanding in memory

Comment: I tried something similar, where I put every single png in 1 animation in the bottom of the viewdidload and had it run through once in a half second interval. It seems to have solved the problem. What is the need for the timer in the animation?